# How do I get Lucia unstuck from the ground?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-hearthfire

My child Lucia is stuck under the world in Skyrim and if I do `player.placeatme`, it's a brand new Lucia that I can't adopt and the original one still exists. I need her out so I can move my family to my new home.

Comment: It's better with a picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the RefID and not the BaseID. You should be able to fix this by following these steps:

1. Type `help Lucia`. You should get a value like `01003F5F`. This is Lucia's BaseID, which will spawn new copies of her.
2. Convert the BaseID into a RefID. For Lucia, just change the last `F` to an `E`. In the above example, you would get `01003F5E`.
3. Use `prid <RefID>`. In this example, you would type `prid 01003F5E`.
4. Finally, use `moveto player` to have Lucia move to you.

Comment: Thank you so much, you won't believe how mad I was getting.

Comment: @PlanetJigsaw if this helped you, choose the tick to make it the accepted answer :)